# View won't go in front of parent view

Tags: ios, storyboard, bringtofront

Basically I have a view that I make a subview of a separate view that I am using as a container the first view however won't go in front of its parent. On the storyboard is shows the child view in front of its parent however on the simulator it is behind.

EDIT - Sorry for the lack of detail let me clarify a bit

This is my XIB I named it SectionCard very basic only containing a single view with a black background
[image]
This is my storyboard all I have done is change the background to red I have added my SectionCard (which I set to clear color) and a basic view as the child of my section card I have set the color of which to pink

[image]
So I thought when I run it I would get my red background a black rectangle with a smaller pink rectangle inside it however for some reason I get this-

[image]
Initially I thought that the pink rectangle view was simply invisible however after commenting the view.frame = self.bounds line and shrinking the SectionCard in the XIB file I noticed that the SectionCard was actually covering up the pink view

[image]
Hopefully this helped explain my issue in more depth any help is appreciated!!!

Comment: I'm afraid we need more details to understand the question

Comment: Shot in the dark here because we need more info but try this: Click on the container in your storyboard, then click on the icon of a triangle in the bottom right corner and click "Reset To Suggested Constraints". See if that does anything

Comment: @SwiftArchitect I just edited the post going into more detail of the issue hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Forcefully bring the view in front like below:

[outerView.view bringSubviewToFront: interview.view]